# Javascript IE error: 'target' is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events

```
document.onkeydown = function(event) {
    var tagName = event.target.tagName;
    if (tagName != 'INPUT' && tagName != 'TEXTAREA' && !event.alt && event.control) {

        if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 37) {
            if (_this.currentPage > 1) {
                window.location.href = _this.baseUrl.replace(/%page%/i, _this.currentPage + 1);
            }
        } else if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 39) {
            if (_this.currentPage < _this.pagesTotal) {
                window.location.href = _this.baseUrl.replace(/%page%/i, _this.currentPage - 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me an error only in IE 8:

> 'target' is null or not an object

for that line `var tagName = event.target.tagName;`

How to fix that? Error happens when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or arrows button.

Comment: `event.target` does not exist in IE8. Welcome to IE's old event system.

Comment: Please can you give an example how to fix that?

Comment: Use a third-party event API what takes care of the cross-browser incompatibilities for you. That would be my advice.

Comment: Yeah, but I am not good at all in Javascript. I need example what to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
event = event || window.event;
var tagName = (event.target || event.srcElement).tagName.toUpperCase();
```

Comment: The same then it gives the same error on the next line `var tagName = event.target.tagName.toUpperCase();`.

Answer (score 6):

IE does not pass in the `event` object into the event handler. Instead, they use the global `event` property of the `window` object. So for IE, you'd use `window.event` instead.

It is common practice to test for the supplied argument first. You also have to take into account the fact the IE uses `srcElement` instead of `target`. To account for all that, use something similar to this:

```
document.onkeydown = function(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var tagName = (event.target || event.srcElement).tagName;
    // Keep up the good work...
}
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: For a second there it looked like a direct copy/paste. Why remove the `toUpperCase`?

Comment: You know I tried that before. It didn't help me. Then it gives the same error on the next line `var tagName = event.target.tagName;`.

Comment: @user1689607 - I just don't think people should still be using quirks mode. I definitely hope the OP is using a proper `doctype`. AFAIK, when in standards mode, IE will return the element's name in uppercase. Someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: There are a couple edge cases for IE (I don't remember which versions).

Comment: Thank you! The additional answer below fix the problem.