# Is e = event || window.event; acceptable for IE8 compatibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

This code (taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13337535/1252748)) has stopped me getting this error message in IE8 when trying to use `preventDefault()`:

> Error: 'null' is null or not an object

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submitBtn").on("click", pD(event));
});

function pD(e) {
    e = event || window.event;
    if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        e.returnValue = false;
    }
}
```

It seems to work. However the comment in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3677799/1252748) (fourth comment down) has me concerned that maybe this is a bad method. Is it acceptable, or unacceptable in some way? The language of the comment is pretty strong, so it makes me wonder.

Comment: should it not be `e = e || window.event`

Comment: There's no point having a function argument `e` if the first line of the function immediately overwrites it with another value. Use karthikr's suggestion so that the argument is used as-is if it has a (truthy) value.

Comment: @nnnnnn okay yeah, typo. so now I get the error `Error: Object required` in the line `if(e.preventDefault){`.

Comment: jQuery's `event` parameter is not a native event object. It's already fixed for you. So why are you trying to fix it again?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly the way you are assigning the click handler is incorrect:

```
$("#submitBtn").on("click", pD(event));
```

You are *invoking* the `pD()` function and passing its return value to the `.on()` method. You need to just pass a reference to the function:

```
$("#submitBtn").on("click", pD);
```

Secondly, you are using jQuery, so you don't need to test the `e` argument and set it to `window.event` because jQuery handles those compatibility issues for you. You can use `e.preventDefault()` knowing jQuery will just make it happen.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you so much. Can you explain, what is it returning that causes the `.on()` method to error?

Comment: `pD(event)` was returning `undefined`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat and when you just pass a reference to it, what does it return then? Does that mean that it doesn't expect a returned value? Bit confused on this, thanks.

Comment: The `.on()` method expects a function reference in that argument, so if you give it one it will be happy. You would pass a reference to your function by putting `pD` _without parentheses_ - with parens it calls your function immediately and passes the return value (`undefined`) to `.on()`. I haven't double-checked the jQuery code, but given that `.on()` has some optional parameters that can be added _before_ the function reference it must be testing the type of its arguments so if you supply an argument that isn't a function reference it might get confused and give the error you showed.

Comment: @nnnnnn Really great to know. Thanks so much!

Comment: Where in the documentation does it specify that `.on()` expects a function reference in that argument. Please bear with me as I'm trying to get my head round it. Thanks.

Comment: In the doco it has an argument `handler(eventObject)`, which it defines (right near the top of the page) as "A function to execute when the event is triggered." There are several examples later on the page, e.g., just under the "The event handler and its environment" heading.